# react router redux initial state setting on isomorphic app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I am writing an isomorphic app with react, redux, react-router, react-router-redux.
I am calling `syncHistoryWithStore` on client.js. But on initial load, `router.locationBeforeTransitions` is always null. It is populated once I navigate though.

```
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);
...

<Router routes={routes} history={history} />
```

Above code is from client.js

Should I fire `LOCATION_CHANGE` action on server side manually to populate initial state of react-router-redux?

Comment: offtopic a bit, but I am getting into isomorphic and curious if you could share any resources you have on doing it?

Comment: sure. I forked from this boilerplate. https://github.com/CrocoDillon/universal-react-redux-boilerplate

Comment: and also https://blog.tableflip.io/server-side-rendering-with-react-and-redux/ explains in detail

Comment: thanks bud, appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You will be creating a new store on client hence the state from the store created on server is lost. We will need to pass the initial state from server to the client, so it can populate its store.

**on Server:**

```
const initialState = store.getState();
```

now add this to your HTML template rendered from server:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
  window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(initialState)};
</script>
```

**on Client**:

```
let initialState = window.__INITIAL_STATE__;
```

use the `initialState` when you [`createStore`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html) on Client.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. FYI, I am already doing that, but I could see that the state for react-router-redux is `{ locationBeforeTransitions : null}`.

Comment: I asked react-router-redux team, and they say I shouldn't map locationBeforeTransitions into props. I should use `locations.pathname` from react-router and it worked fine!